# Why we need to create method in subclass to acess methods in Superclass in Java programming language.?

Tags: java, oop

I am currently learning OOP in java. One thing I came across is that, for example, i have a method speed in Vehicle SUPERCLASS, and I want to access that method in SUBCLASS Car, i will have to create method like;

```
public void changespeed()
{
  super.speed();
}
```

in order to access speed method. My question is, why we need to enclose speed method like that in order to access it? why cant we just simply use this approach;

```
super.speed();
```

to call that speed method in subclass. ?

Comment: ALL Java statements must be included in a method of some sort.  You can define variables outside a method, but everything else is within methods, even if it is just the `Main()` method or an object's constructor (which is a method). Where are you hoping to be able to call `super.speed()` if not in a method? How would Java ever execute that code if not part of a method?

Comment: If `Vehicle.speed()` is *`public`* then you **can** call `Car.speed()` (`Car` will inherit the method from `Vehicle`).

Comment: Yes,I want to know the reason behind why we need to enclose such statements in methods? @Zephyr

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please read my question again, I am not calling it from main class, I am calling method of SUPERCLASS in SUBCLASS, and yes it is public.

Comment: @calculusnoob I don't understand your question, and you don't need to shout. I know what superclasses and subclasses are. You can call `speed` in the subclass without calling `changespeed`; in fact `super.speed()` and `this.speed()` in the sub-class (absent any overrides) are the same thing.

Comment: Bottom line, methods are where all the execution of Java takes place. So if you want something to HAPPEN in Java, it needs to be in a method.  Ask why that is is like asking why it has to be in English or why does it have to be called Java? It's just the syntax of the language.

Comment: What do you mean "access it"? Who's calling it? When? Why?

Comment: You don't need the `super` in that case, @calculusnoob. Many coders include the `super` to make it clear they're referring to the method in the parent class. But you could also just call `super()` within your `Mercedes` class with the same result.

Comment: But your question is not very clear and your comments seem to contradict what you're actually asking...

Comment: Perhaps you should include a full code example of what you believe is required and what you were expecting to be possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
speed();
```

Since non-private superclass methods are all inherited by the subclass, `speed` also exists in the subclass. You can access it by `this.speed()`, or just `speed()`.

Obviously, you have to put this method call in an appropriate place. You can't just randomly put it in a class like this:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
    speed(); // can't do this!
}
```

You have to put the method call in, among other things, another method or a constructor. This way the compiler knows when the method will be called.

> Why do method calls have to be in other methods or constructors?

Well, ask yourself when the method call in the above snippet will be called. Remember that `speed` is an instance method, so an instance of `Car` is needed to call it. Where's that instance? This whole notion of putting methods directly in a class makes little sense.

> So what if I want a method to be called when the class is loaded?

You can use a static block for that purpose:

```
static {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Note that you still can't call `speed` directly in a static block because you need an instance of `Car` or `Vehicle`.